# How to set Uninstall Successful message in WixStdBA

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

In WiX 3.9 and earlier, there was no way to customize the message that WixStdBA shows when the operation completed.  I see that bugs [4149](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4149/) and [4604](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4604/) have been resolved as fixed.  Which version of WiX are these fixes available in, and how do I use this new functionality?

Answer (score 1):

In WiX v3.10.0.1403, support was added for specifying different strings for success/failure of install/repair/uninstall.  If you're using the builtin theme and localization file, then you get the new strings automatically.  Otherwise, look at the [pull request](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/pull/188/files) to see what was added to the builtin themes and localization files and put them in your customized files.

In WiX v4.0.2603.0, breaking changes were made to the schema of theme files.  As part of that change, the `Text` element was renamed to `Label` and the new `Text` element allows conditionally setting the text of a control.  In WiX v4.0.2926.0, the builtin themes and localization files were updated to show the same text as v3.10 does.  Take a look at that [commit](https://github.com/rseanhall/wix4/commit/650b9f77dab3d3acfd5580f7d2415549b41f3544) to see how that functionality was added.